# Como limitar o numero de casas decimais de uma propriedade tipo FLOAT com Data Annotation na Model da Tabela utilizando EF do C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dataannotations

```
    public class Alunos
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        ["format(0.00F)"]  <-  QUAL A SINTAXE PARA FAZER ESSA FORMATAÇÃO NA MODEL DO EF
        public float Media { get; set; }
    }
```

Preciso truncar as casas decimais para evitar que o Entity Framework salve no Banco com o número máximo de de casas decimais permitida por um campo float.

Exemplo se eu envio o valor 1.12

Ele salva no banco o valor 1.1199999255845669

Obs. se eu fizer o insert direto no Banco ele inseri apenas duas casa decimais 1.12, esse problema só acontece quando o EF persiste os dados.

Comment: Qual versão do EF?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558549/validate-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-with-data-annotations

Comment: Por que não usar `decimal` ao invés de `float` nesse caso?

Comment: @BrunoWarmling Entity Framework 6

Comment: @NatanFernandes a resposta que eu obtive foi para economia de memória ja que o Decimal utiliza 4x mais memoria que o float

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: Infelizmente se você usar o float vai acabar perdendo essas casas decimais

Answer (score -1):

A solução encontrada foi convencer a equipe a Utilizar o Decimal, como questionou o [Natan Fernandes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/202406/natan-fernandes)

```
Decimal(6.5) //para formato 1.12345
Decimal(10.2) //para formato 12345678.12
```